# Load a 16-bit DLL into a 32-bit Process on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64, 32-bit, 16-bit

I wrote a 32-bit application that launches a 16-bit executable, which loads some 16-bit DLLs to perform some of the application's functions.  It runs fine on Windows 7 32-bit, but not on Windows 7 64-bit since that version of the OS does not include the NTVDM.

The 16-bit portion of the code is pretty extensive and would be pretty expensive to port to 32-bit.  Also, it uses some 3rd-party 16-bit APIs from a company that is no longer in business; therefore, that code would have to be recreated completely, thereby increasing the cost.

**Is there any possible way to simply load the existing 16-bit DLLs directly from the 32-bit application, removing the 16-bit executable completely?**

I've looked into thunking, but it doesn't appear that is supported in Windows 7 either.

Comment: Even if you could load it, how do you plan on executing it? The 16-bit code expects a different processor architecture, and none of the support DLLs will be there, and even if they were, they would try to communicate with a kernel that isn't there.

Comment: if the program's extensive then it'll take advantage when recompile to 32 or 64-bit code, especially in 64-bit mode where there are double the registers. You should look for or write an alternative API, which may be much more powerful than the old one. Only in the case there's really isn't possible then use an emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an emulator or a virtual machine.

Or, if that is not an option then you *can* write a primitive emulator yourself, read the machinecode instruction-by-instruction and modify fake-registers and memory accordingly, and when the program calls outward then you will have to generate responses.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible in Windows.